# In Android, What does the "Adjust is running in Production mode" mean?

Tags: android, logcat, production, dev-to-production

When I run my app, I see a message in the logcat:

```
F/Adjust  ( 8224): PRODUCTION: Adjust is running in Production mode. Use this setting only for the build that you want to publish. Set the environment to `sandbox` if you want to test your app!
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.adjust.com/

The log message seems to be coming from [here](https://github.com/adjust/android_sdk/blob/master/Adjust/adjust/src/main/java/com/adjust/sdk/AdjustConfig.java), and would suggest that you are using the Adjust analytics SDK, and that is configured to run in Production mode.

Comment: But y is it using Adjust? I didn't do anything to add it, and I can't find the string "adjust" in my code.

Comment: Some other app you have installed on your device will be using it in that case.

Comment: Is there any way to find out which 1?

Comment: You could investigate whether the SDK runs in the same process ID as its host app, then determine which app the 8224 process is.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like more than I intended to spend on this issue... I think I'll leave it for now. Thanx for your efforts!

Comment: In my case there was the Viber app who logged that.